# MS Access: Update statement with several joins

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a table (`DMS_TEST_LOAD`) based on two other tables (`TDCE_NE` and `TDCE_NE_COMP`).  Any idea what is wrong with the below query? I keep getting the useless "Syntax error in UPDATE statement." error from Access. Thanks in advance.

```
UPDATE DMS_TEST_LOAD AS DMS 
((INNER JOIN TDCE_NE_COMP AS COMP
ON COMP.[NAME] LIKE DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)] AND COMP.[NE_COMP_TYPE_ID]=421)
INNER JOIN TDCE_NE AS NE ON NE.[ID]=COMP.[NE_ID] AND NE.[NAME]=DMS.[Office])
SET DMS.[Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)] = COMP.[CHAR_PARM1];
```

Comment: do you not need from before the inner join?

Comment: Why don't you just build it in Access "Design view" ? It will write the statement for you.

Comment: @iDevlop because Access will develop the query in the simplest, most inefficient way possible and my query will take forever to run.

Comment: @user1947544 perhaps, but it can be a good starting point and a time saver to build a first version that works.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what SQL system MS access uses. But you might want to try this

```
UPDATE DMS
SET DMS.[Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)] = COMP.[CHAR_PARM1]
FROM DMS_TEST_LOAD AS DMS
 INNER JOIN TDCE_NE_COMP AS COMP
   ON COMP.[NAME] LIKE DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)]
      AND COMP.[NE_COMP_TYPE_ID]=421
  INNER JOIN TDCE_NE AS NE
     ON NE.[ID]=COMP.[NE_ID] AND NE.[NAME]=DMS.[Office];
```

Comment: No luck, @Alex.  Unfortunately, MS Access doesn't have intuitive syntax such as that.  I believe the joins must come prior to setting DMS.[Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)].

Comment: found an example here : http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/query/snytax/update-query.html#UPDATE_Query_SQL_Syntax
    UPDATE tblAddress
    INNER JOIN tblZipCodes ON [tblAddress].[ZipCode] =  [tblZipCodes].[ZipCode]
    SET [tblAddress].[City]  = [tblZipCodes].[City], 
    [tblAddress].[State] = [tblZipCodes].[State]
    WHERE ([Country] = 'US')

Comment: could the problem be with your like? would you need to compare a string with another string?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236410/access-query-where-one-field-is-like-another

Comment: I think the like statement is part of the issue.  I am trying to formulate my join statement properly now, but I still keep getting the same error.  As an update, I have using all of the proposed solutions (from Alex, Rich Andrews, and Linger) with no success;  it's the same syntax error.

Comment: maybe cast the field to the left of the like to string like this CStr(DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)]) ?

Answer (score 0):

In MS Access you have to make sure you use the parenthesis correctly in the joins.  I do believe you are after the following:

```
UPDATE DMS
SET DMS.[Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)] = COMP.CHAR_PARM1
FROM (DMS_TEST_LOAD AS DMS
  INNER JOIN TDCE_NE_COMP AS COMP 
    ON (COMP.NAME = DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)]) AND (COMP.NE_COMP_TYPE_ID = 421)) 
  INNER JOIN TDCE_NE AS NE 
    ON (NE.Name = DMS.Office) AND (COMP.NE_ID = NE.ID)
```

Note I removed the `LIKE` and replaced it with `=`.  You were not using any wild cards so it wasn't even functioning as a `LIKE`.  If you want to use the `LIKE` you may be looking for the following:

```
COMP.NAME LIKE "*" & DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)] & "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this...

```
UPDATE DMS
SET [Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)] = COMP.[CHAR_PARM1] 
FROM DMS_TEST_LOAD DMS
INNER JOIN TDCE_NE_COMP AS COMP
    ON COMP.[NAME] LIKE DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)] 
    AND COMP.[NE_COMP_TYPE_ID]=421
INNER JOIN TDCE_NE AS NE 
    ON NE.[ID]=COMP.[NE_ID] 
    AND NE.[NAME]=DMS.[Office]
```

Not tested but refactored to ANSI92 "standard" SQL

And can be tested (without actually doing the update ofc) with...

```
SELECT [Char Parm 1 (Trk Dir)],  COMP.[CHAR_PARM1] 
FROM DMS_TEST_LOAD DMS
INNER JOIN TDCE_NE_COMP AS COMP
    ON COMP.[NAME] LIKE DMS.[Trunk Group Number (TGN)] 
    AND COMP.[NE_COMP_TYPE_ID]=421
INNER JOIN TDCE_NE AS NE 
    ON NE.[ID]=COMP.[NE_ID] 
    AND NE.[NAME]=DMS.[Office]
```